# Find an invalid record ID in a list of potential ID's

Tags: mysql

Given a list of potential ID's is there a quick way using a single MYSQL query to work out which, if any, of the ID's do not have an associated record in the database.

e.g. if the list is 1,3,4 and records exist for 1 and 4 but not 3 is there a query that will return 3 from the list.

This needs to be applied to a database containing 15000 records checking against a list of 1 to 100 IDs which may contain zero or more invalid IDs. The list is sourced externally and not in another table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry about my previous answer - my bad, I read the question too quickly.

There's no clean way to do this in pure SQL (clean meaning not involving ugly subqueries, unions, or temp tables).  If it were me, I'd probably do it something like this (assuming PHP):

```
$all_ids = array(1, 3, 4);
$query = "SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE id IN (" . implode(',', $all_ids) . ")";
$found_ids = getArrayFromQuery($query);
$invalid_ids = array_diff($all_ids, $found_ids);
```

Comment: Thanks. That's eminently usable!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT idtable.id, records.id as rid FROM idtable 
LEFT JOIN records ON idtable.id = records.id
WHERE rid IS NULL
```

Comment: This solution appears to require creating a new table to hold the list then putting the list into that new table before comparing it with the existing table? {question edited to explain list is not already in another table}

Comment: had the same misunderstanding as beamrider had it. his solution is good :-)